# Select check boxes

Tags: install4j

On a form in my installer I have a set of check boxes.
Now I want another check box, that when selected will select the other check boxes

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the "Selection script" property of your checkbox form component, add the following code:

```
((JCheckBox)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("123").
      getConfigurationObject()).setSelected(selected);
```

where "123" has to be replaced with the ID of the other form component that should be selected.

Comment: is there a way to set the ID via the IDE?  Unless I'm missing something, using the number requires me to first manually find the number in the generated xml file, and it seems to me that the number would be prone to changing through changes to the installer.  I tried naming the component and using that name, but that didn't work...  Thanks.

Comment: The ID of a check box will never change, but you assign one manually. When you invoke the rename action for the form component, there is a check box in the input dialog for assigning an ID. Custom IDs have to start with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Simple with something like jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // On clicking the master, check all checkbox
    $("#checkall").click(function() {
        // find all checkboxes with the class 'checkboxes'
        // and make it checked/unchecked to match the master checkbox
        $('input[type="checkbox"].checkboxes')
           .attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"))
       ;
    });
});
</script>
```

Add a Simple Checkbox to act as a master to enable/disable the rest

```
<input title="Check all" id="checkall" 
       type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" 
/>

<input class="checkboxes checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input class="checkboxes checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input class="checkboxes checkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I am a complete novice and dont understand your code! I tried it but it wont compile. Could you please explain a little further

Comment: You would need to look at the jquery library, it will make any javascrupt usage a lot easier for a novice! jquery.com

Comment: AFAIK, install4j doesn't support jquery in it's actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple javascript to do it:

```
<div id="page">
<p>
<input id="chkFile1" type="checkbox" title="File 1" />File 1</p>
<p>
<input id="chkFile2" type="checkbox" title="File 2" />File 2</p>
<p>
<input id="chkFile3" type="checkbox" title="File 3" />File 3</p>
<p>
<input id="chkFile4" type="checkbox" title="File 4" />File 4</p>
<p>
<input id="chkFile5" type="checkbox" title="File 5" />File 5</p>
<p>
<input id="chkAllFiles" type="checkbox" title="All Files"  onchange="selectAllFiles(this.checked);" />All Files</p>
</div>
```

then the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectAllFiles(c) {
       for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
           document.getElementById('chkFile' + i).checked = c;
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, where do I enter this code in the Install4j IDE?

Comment: Sorry. I am not familiar with this IDE.

Comment: AFAIK, install4j doesn't support javascript in it's actions.